# how to run the settings migration command?

Tags: magento2, data-migration

how to run the setting migration command in macOS?
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-settings.html

my current command looks like this but getting error:

```
[Migration\Exception]                                                                     
  Invalid config filename: {/Users/brodyr/Documents/Sites/Magento/vendor/magento/data-migr  
  ation-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/config.xml}
```

this is my command

```
php magento migrate:settings {/Users/brodyr/Documents/Sites/Magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/config.xml}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should run the command as

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings -r -vvv C:/Users/brodyr/Documents/Sites/Magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/config.xml
```

Exclude the curly braces {} this should work!

an alternative command is:
        php ./magento

PS
    -r is to restart and -vvv is to debug~!

Answer (score 0):

To run the migrate settings use below command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings /var/www/html/Magentofresh/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.1.0/config.xml
```

and to run the migrate data:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data /var/www/html/Magentofresh/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.1.0/config.xml
```

You will require to set Databases of M1 and M2 in file **config.xml** file.

Hope this will help you.